# Problem relating to circumscribing the escribed sircles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The triangle DEF circumscribes the three escribed circles of the triangle ABC.
I have to prove that

$$\dfrac{EF}{a \cos A} = \dfrac{FD}{b \cos B}= \dfrac{DE}{c \cos C}.$$
Also, point D is opposite to A. E is opposite to B. F is opposite to C

I am not able to find the angles of the triangle DEF. Help me

Comment: Do you have any graph? Maybe of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275167/a-geometry-problem-about-inscribed-and-circumscribed-circle-radius?rq=1